# Limitations NodeJS runtime in in Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am planning to use node JS on google app engine. I wanted to understand the limitations before I make a decision. I know there are many libraries the app engine provides by default. Can I use all those if I use a Node JS run time? and what are some other limitations?

Comment: I hope you're aware that app engine does **not** support node.js natively... node.js on app engine works through managed VMs and uses a docker container. There should be no restrictions in a docker container that restrict your node js libraries, like there should not be restrictions in any IaaS VM. Could be wrong though - I just wanted to point out that it is not natively supported.

Comment: With the latest gcloud release, Docker is also no longer required for deploying NodeJS apps.  You can run app locally with npm start and include an app.yaml file for the resource configuration for deploying to Google Cloud Platform.  This is through managed VMs.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, isn't managed VM still in beta? can I use it for a production project?

Comment: Karthikkumar I just asked it here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/issues/12